# Rvest: Building a queue for several html-links

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm currently webscraping a news magazine, but unfortunately, I don't have a clue on how to establish a working queue. I can only scrape the content of all articles on one page, but I want a queue, that automatically does the same thing for the rest of articles.

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(writexl)


map_dfc(.x = c("em.entrylist__title", "time.entrylist__time"),
        .f = function(x) {read_html("https://www.sueddeutsche.de/news/page/1?search=Corona&sort=date&all%5B%5D=dep&all%5B%5D=typ&all%5B%5D=sys&time=2020-07-19T00%3A00%2F2020-07-27T23%3A59&startDate=27.07.2020&endDate=01.08.2020") %>% 
            html_nodes(x) %>% 
            html_text()}) %>%
  bind_cols(url = read_html("https://www.sueddeutsche.de/news/page/1?search=Corona&sort=date&all%5B%5D=dep&all%5B%5D=typ&all%5B%5D=sys&time=2020-07-19T00%3A00%2F2020-07-27T23%3A59&startDate=27.07.2020&endDate=01.08.2020") %>% 
              html_nodes("a.entrylist__link") %>% 
              html_attr("href")) %>% 
  setNames(nm = c("title", "time", "url")) -> temp

map_df(.x = temp$url[1:50],
       .f = function(x){tibble(url = x,
                               text = read_html(x) %>% 
                                 html_nodes("#article-app-container > article > div.css-isuemq.e1lg1pmy0 > p:nth-child(n)") %>% 
                                 html_text() %>% 
                                 list
       )}) %>% 
  unnest(text) -> foo

foo

X2 <- ddply(foo, .(url), summarize,
            Xc=paste(text,collapse=","))

final <- merge(temp, X2, by="url")
```

In this case, I got 30 pages filled with articles, but my scripts only supports the scraping of one page.
The only thing that changes in between the pages is the page number (https://www.sueddeutsche.de/news/**page/1**?search=...)

If you could give me a hint on how to include all pages into the queue at once, I would be more than grateful. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hint: `lapply`, or `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would a queue in dataframe form work for you?
The following suggestion is held a little more generic, so it'll work beyond the specific use-case. You would be able to add more URLs to scrape as you go, but only *new* ones will be kept, due to `dplyr::distinct`.
(I've initiated the queue to hold the first 5 pages you want to scrape, you can add more right away or dynamically if you find links on the DOM...)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

queue <- tibble(
  url = paste0("https://www.sueddeutsche.de/news/page/", 1:5, "?search=Corona&sort=date&all%5B%5D=dep&all%5B%5D=typ&all%5B%5D=sys&time=2020-07-19T00%3A00%2F2020-07-27T23%3A59&startDate=27.07.2020&endDate=01.08.2020"),
  scraped_time = lubridate::NA_POSIXct_
)

results <- list()

while(length(open_rows <- which(is.na(queue$scraped_time))) > 0) {
  i <- open_rows[1]
  url <- queue$url[i]

  [...]
  results[[url]] <- <YOUR SCRAPING RESULT>
  
  queue$scraped_time[i] <- lubridate::now()
  
  if (<MORE PAGES TO QUEUE>) {
    queue <- queue %>%
      tibble::add_row(url = c('www.spiegel.de', 'www.faz.de')) %>%
      arrange(desc(scraped_time)) %>%
      distinct(url, .keep_all = T)
  }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot! In order to let the loop work, I would need to insert a variable instead of the same html ("https://www.sueddeutsche.de/news/page/1?search=Corona&sort=date&all%5B%5D=dep&all%5B%5D=typ&all%5B%5D=sys&time=2020-07-19T00%3A00%2F2020-07-27T23%3A59&startDate=27.07.2020&endDate=01.08.2020")

Which variable do I use in this context, url[i] for indexing? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you know the number of pages you want ahead of time, just adjust the `1:5` in the `paste0` statement. It will create the URL vector by inserting the page numbers you specify